# React Hook "useGetCompanyAvatar" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs, request, react-query

So I am basically having a request that puts a new Avatar as main image :

```
 if (fileList.length) {
  console.log(fileList[0]);
  Api.companies
    .putCompanyAvatar(
      company?.id as string,
      new Blob([fileList[0].originFileObj as any], { type: 'application/jpeg' }),
    )
    .then(() => {
      setFileList([]);
      client.invalidateQueries(['company-avatar']);
      setCompanyAv(useGetCompanyAvatar());
    });
}
};
```

And on the then() func I also want to do another get function which is useGetCompanyAvatar to get the new picture I put in the put request.

And then I get this error :

> React Hook "useGetCompanyAvatar" cannot be called inside a callback.

useGetCompanyAvatar :

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import { Api } from "../index";

const useGetCompanyAvatar = (
companyId: string | undefined,
) => {
   const query = () => {
return Api.companies.getCompanyAvatar(companyId);
};

const { isLoading, data: companyAvatar } = useQuery(
["company-avatar"],
    query,
     {
  select: (r) => URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([r?.data as any], { type: 
    r?.headers['content-type'] }))
 }
);

return {
isLoading,
companyAvatar,
};
};

export default useGetCompanyAvatar;
```

So why can I not to another get to update the new current Avatar?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling useQuery (or a custom hook wrapping useQuery) directly as an async function. It's a hook and must follow the rules of hooks. If you just take out that `setCompanyAv` call and instead relied on the cache-invalidation you're already doing to update the avatar I think it'd work the way you intend.